# mysql sql case statement gives same value for different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying a simple case query in W3School page.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_2

When I run following query, I keep getting 'over' for all range values. It should show 'under' for price below 500.

```
SELECT 
(o.Quantity* p.Price) as price,
case price when price< 500 
           then 'under' 
           else 'over' 
           end as range 
 FROM OrderDetails o 
 inner join Products p 
 on (o.ProductID = p.ProductID)
```

Comment: I think the query may be interpreting "price" as the price in the table, not the calculated field. Try making the names different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS `price` column exists in Products table, it is using that value

you can't reference the column alias `price` in the same select statement, you need to repeat the `price` calculation

Also you are mixing two kinds of case expression

you have

```
case price when price <500
```

you should use

```
case when (o.Quantity* p.Price) < 500
```

Comment: I updated query as per suggestion. Still same result       SELECT 
(o.Quantity* p.Price) as price_val,
case (o.Quantity* p.Price) when (o.Quantity* p.Price)< 500 
           then 'under' 
           else 'over' 
           end as range 
 FROM OrderDetails o 
 inner join Products p 
 on (o.ProductID = p.ProductID)

Comment: Ok got it right this time here is final query. Thanks! SELECT 
(o.Quantity* p.Price) as price_val,
case  when (o.Quantity* p.Price)< 500 
           then 'under' 
           else 'over' 
           end as range 
 FROM OrderDetails o 
 inner join Products p 
 on (o.ProductID = p.ProductID)

Comment: Remove calculation between case and when, no expression between case and when have it only after when